# Favicon is completely transparent?

Tags: html, favicon, web-standards

There's an indentation indicating that my favicon was loaded, but instead of seeing the favicon, I see a completely blank region where the favicon should be.  The image is 38x48, but I also tried 32x32.  It's about 10kb for the 48x48, 5kb for the 32x32.  It's certainly not a blank/transparent image.

This is what I see when I load the **favicon**: [image: an browser-bar tab is shown with an indentation where the favicon should be.]

This is what I see when I load *no favicon*: [image: a browser-bar tab is shown with no indentation, indicating that no favicon was loaded.]

Can you see the difference?  I should be seeing a picture of a leaf swaddling a baby's cheek with bird saliva that's been transformed into honey.

*I put this under compliance because I thought it might be an issue of the image size, dimensions, or something else very nitche.

Here's the head.  I wonder if it's because I'm in China and W3C may not be accessible....  I'm going to try quirks mode, next.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="..." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="..." />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/index.ico" />
<!-- Style link START -->
    <link rel=stylesheet media="screen" type="text/css" size="48x48" href="screen.css">
<!-- Style link END -->
</head>
```

Comment: What format is your favicon? Icons are fairly standard, especially since a single icon file can contain multiple sizes.

Comment: `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">`

Comment: That href is only to going to work if the favicon is in the same directory as the page you're viewing. Have you tried changing that to an absolute path or root-relative path?

Comment: have you checked the console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: The favicon is in the same directory.

Comment: There's no error or warning reported in the console.  Actually, the code that results in an indentation is `<...href="/favicon.ico">`.  without the `/`, there's no indentation.  I also thought it may have been because the directory was encrypted, but I de-encrypted the directory, and I still have the same issue.  Do you think clearing the cache might work?

Comment: I would try using a different favicon, perhaps from a site where you *can* see the favicon, to determine whether it's an issue with the icon itself.

Comment: @TiesonT. I've used an .ico that works on other sites (freelancer.com), and it hasn't worked; so, it must be the code, itself.

Comment: "it must be the code" - probably, but since you haven't posted any...

Comment: Well, the second comment.  Hmm.  Let me edit things.

Comment: I've had similar issues with favicons.. are you sure the PNG you are using is  valid? I've had similar issues when the PNG I was using turned out not to be semi-corrupt, in the sense that it wasn't recognized correctly by a browser (for instance, odd transparency borders or color depth). I've never really looked into why, but anyway. Have you tried other PNGs? Here, try this [one](https://db.tt/QW7SoVYN). [Here](https://db.tt/oXYDggV8) is how I use it.

Comment: @Russell I'm using .ico files, I've tested ico's that work for me on other sites.  I've scanned the files, and they don't seem to be corrupt.

Comment: Interesting. I provided a PNG based on the first answer, sorry I do see now you're using .icos now. Have you checked the permissions of the .ico file? The `/` should definitely be removed, especially since it's already in the same directory. Perms have gotten me before.

Answer (score 1):

Favicons have to be of various sizes for different types of browsers.
It's important that the sizes are correct for each browser.
You seem to be using mozilla, so use an image which is either:

- 16 x 16
- 32 x 32
- 48 x 48
- 62 x 62

All in pixels.
Here's the code:

```
<!-- For IE 11, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera -->  
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon-16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon-32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon-48.png" sizes="48x48" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon-62.png" sizes="62x62" type="image/png">
<!-- More info: https://bitsofco.de/all-about-favicons-and-touch-icons/ -->
```

Hope this worked.

Comment: I wish it had.  I added the "size" attribute, and it didn't work.

Comment: Tweak the size of the original image and experiment with it.

Comment: I guess you can mark this as solved, then, according to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this myself to see if I could get it to work. It did not work with an ico file named "index.ico" However, it did work when I renamed the ico file to "favicon.ico". if that does not work you can also try with other file formats. PNG and JPG always work for me no matter the name.

Also make sure that your ico file is converted correctly and that you have not just renamed it to an ico file. There are many converters out there where you can convert other images files to ico files.

**Edit:** Afterwards I tried with several different random names and they all worked, all except from index.ico

Comment: Strangely enough, the issue just resolved itself.  I have no idea as to why.  It's possible that some other part of the document was interfering because I've been editing for quite a while, now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's some cache issue because the problem resolves itself over time.  I've tried changing the favicon, and it doesn't change until a significant amount of time elapses.  I'd like to learn more about this behavior and understand why it occurs.